# Linear operators and linear dependence

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Let $u,v \in V$, where $V$ is a $\mathbb{K}$-vector space.
>
> Show that if $T(u) = 0$ implies $T(v) = 0$ for all $T \in V^*$,
>
> then $v=ku$, for some $k \in \mathbb{K}$.

---

I tried to define a linear operator $T$ such that $\ker T = \{ku : k \in \mathbb{K}\}$, but couldn't do so.

Is there a way to construct such $T$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: I assume that $V$ is finite dimensional. Suppose that $u,v$ are linear independent, there exists $e_1,...,e_n$ such that $(u,v,e_1,...,e_n)$ is a basis, defines $u^*(u)=1, u^*(v)=0, u^*(e_i)=0$.

Comment: Of course the same proof works if $V$ is infinite dimensional as well.